# To Delete a tape from the ACSLSlibrary

Tags: tape, netbackup

Hi Anyone there can help me out for an issue as below:

There was a stuck tape in the drive and so the stuck tape was removed, but i need to logically delete the tape entry from NB, so that the same media can be inserted back for operations.

Netback thinks that the tape is still in that location, hence it should be removed so that the entry is not there and NB does not recognise that the tape in that location, so the same tape can be taken in through inventory. The NB used is NB5.1

Any command to delete this entry, this is a clustered based Environment (Active/Passive), and we use a ACSLS library (Physical) as well a Switch-SN6000(Logical)

Kindly help me out as when we tried to delete the media from GUI it said- Could not delete- Cannot delete assigned volume (92).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to throw away this tape, and use totally different tape with the same barcode label. In this case you would need to erase from the NetBackup internal database all the backups that were on this tape using this undocumented command:

```
bpexpdate -d 0 -m YOURTAPE
```

Of course this means you will not be able to restore any of these backups.
After you do this, NetBackup will allow you to delete the tape from the database.

By the way, NetBackup is traditionally abbreviated as "NBU".